# Can WP plugins access files outside the installation folder?

Tags: php, filesystem

If I have multiple WP installations in let's say /var/www. Can a plugin be developed to access files outside its own directory?

I want to host multiple installations for different customers in the same chroot. But those customers will have admin access to their instance. Can they theoretically develop a WP plugin to access the files (or even WP config, including DB credentials) of another WP installation?

For example, can the WP located at /var/www/wordpress-customer-1 access files located at /var/www/wordpress-customer-2 ?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not WordPress specific, you'll probably get better answers [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or other more server oriented communities. The short answer is probably: yes they can and you need to do something against it. The answer would be that you need some kind of virtualization (Docker e.g.) or a more specific right management in your one box to solve this issue. (The problem with your setup right now is that it is the same PHP process who works on /var/www/a and /var/www/b, so yes it can access all of these files.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can they theoretically develop a WP plugin to access the files (or even WP config, including DB credentials) of another WP installation?

Yes.

If your folders are owned by the same user, run as the same user in Apache/Nginx or have read/write access to each other, then it's possible.

Your installations are sandboxed at the server/host level, not the WP level.If your users have the ability to upload plugins or edit PHP, then they can easily upload a version of the `emergency.php` targeted at the other installs and reset the admin password. Likewise they could insert a PHP shell, or read the `wp-config.php` of the other install.

It's also much worse, if one of those sites gets hacked, all of them could be infected. You also have a more difficult time with backups

If you are concerned for security, you should fix this immediately. How you would fix that is server specific and not in the scope of this site. Consider asking on ServerFault